# Spark SQL CSV to JSON with different data types

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Currently, I have a csv data like this:

```
id,key,value
id_1,int_key,1
id_1,string_key,asd
id_1,double_key,null
id_2,double_key,2.0
```

I'd like to transform these attributes grouped by their id with their corresponding correct data type to json.

I'm expecting to have a json structure like this:

```
[{
  id: "id_1"
  attributes: {
    int_key: 1,
    string_key: "asd"
    double_key: null
  }
},
  id: "id_2"
  attributes: {
    double_key: 2.0
  }]
```

My current solution is to collect_list with to_json in Spark which looked like this:

```
SELECT to_json(id, map_from_arrays(collect_list(key), collect_list(value)) as attributes GROUP BY id)
```

This will work however, I cannot find a way to cast to their correct data types.

```
[{
  id: "id_1"
  attributes: {
    int_key: "1",
    string_key: "asd"
    double_key: "null"
  }
},
  id: "id_2"
  attributes: {
    double_key: "2.0"
  }]
```

I also need to add support to null values. But I already found a solution for that. I use ignoreNulls option in to_json. So, if I tried to enumerate each attributes and cast them to their corresponding type, I will be including all the attributes defined. I just want to include the attributes of the user defined in the csv file.

By the way, I'm using Spark 2.4.

Answer (score 0):

**Python:** Here is my PySpark version of the conversion from the scala version. The results are the same.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, max, struct

df = spark.read.option("header","true").csv("test.csv")
keys = [row.key for row in df.select(col("key")).distinct().collect()]

df2 = df.groupBy("id").pivot("key").agg(max("value"))
df2.show()
df2.printSchema()

for key in keys:
    df2 = df2.withColumn(key, col(key).cast(key.split('_')[0]))
df2.show()
df2.printSchema()

df3 = df2.select("id", struct("int_key", "double_key", "string_key").alias("attributes"))
jsonArray = df3.toJSON().collect()

for json in jsonArray: print(json)
```

---

**Scala:** I tried to split each type of value by using the `pivot` first.

```scala
val keys = df.select('key).distinct.rdd.map(r => r(0).toString).collect
val df2 = df.groupBy('id).pivot('key, keys).agg(max('value))
df2.show
df2.printSchema
```

Then, the DataFrame looks like below:

```
+----+-------+----------+----------+
|  id|int_key|double_key|string_key|
+----+-------+----------+----------+
|id_2|   null|       2.0|      null|
|id_1|      1|      null|       asd|
+----+-------+----------+----------+

root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- int_key: string (nullable = true)
 |-- double_key: string (nullable = true)
 |-- string_key: string (nullable = true)
```

where the type of each column is still strings. 
To cast it, I have used the `foldLeft`,

```scala
val df3 = keys.foldLeft(df2) { (df, key) => df.withColumn(key, col(key).cast(key.split("_").head)) }
df3.show
df3.printSchema
```

and the result now have collrect types.

```
+----+-------+----------+----------+
|  id|int_key|double_key|string_key|
+----+-------+----------+----------+
|id_2|   null|       2.0|      null|
|id_1|      1|      null|       asd|
+----+-------+----------+----------+

root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- int_key: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- double_key: double (nullable = true)
 |-- string_key: string (nullable = true)
```

Then, you can build your json such as

```scala
val df4 = df3.select('id, struct('int_key, 'double_key, 'string_key) as "attributes")
val jsonArray = df4.toJSON.collect
jsonArray.foreach(println)
```

where the last line is for checking the result that is

```
{"id":"id_2","attributes":{"double_key":2.0}}
{"id":"id_1","attributes":{"int_key":1,"string_key":"asd"}}
```